# How to place stored procedure in desired location?

Tags: sql, sql-server

On SQL Server 2008, how can I place my stored procedures in "Stored Procedures" folder of my DB?

When I declare it this way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mySchema.myProc
```

It goes to:

```
MYSERVER\System Databases\Master\Programmability\Stored procedures folder.
```

How to tell server, to store it in:

```
MYSERVER\System Databases\MYDB\Programmability\Stored procedures folder.
```

EDIT:

If I declare it like that:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [myDB].mySchema.myProc
```

It complains about:

```
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.
```

If I use the 'USE' keyword, It complains:

```
a USE database statement is not allowed in a procedure, function or trigger.
```

Maybe the problem is that I'm using MS Management Studio, and connecting directly to the server, and not to any particular DB?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but can't you do this by select the database first? Or say CREATE PROCEDURE [mydb].mySchema.myProc

Comment: No. It complains: 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name.

Comment: Then try the following    USE MyDb GO CREATE PROCEDURE mySchema.myProc

Comment: Thank you Rob, that do the trick.

Comment: Problem could be indeed that you're connecting directly to an online server. You're most likely not always allowed to create stored procedures on an online database at a hosting company.

Comment: @kofucci you're welcome! I'll add my comment as answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the following

```
USE MyDb 
GO 
CREATE PROCEDURE mySchema.myProc
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you are creating the procedure in master database instead of your database.
Add `Use MYDB` above the create script of the stored procedure and it will be created in your database.